# MongoDB custom sorting with the other values?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I'd like to be able to sort this collection according to the following attributes of each item.

```js
var distance1 = { velocity : 100, time: 20, rank: time*velocity};
var distance2 = { velocity : 50, time: 25, rank: time*velocity};
var distance3 = { velocity : 300, time: 10, rank: time*velocity};

collection.insert([distance1, distance2, distance3]);
```

So basically rank them in accordance of 'distance' (time*velocity) in ascending order.

The list should end up as this;

1. distance2
2. distance1
3. distance3

However, the rank needs to be derived from the distance and velocity containers, since otherwise you'd run into a problem when the user changes the values;

```js
distance1.set(time= "1");
distance1.set(velocity = "1");

distance2.set(time= "100");
distance2.set(velocity = "20");

distance3.set(time= "10000");
distance3.set(velocity = "20000");
```

Which should the rank to;

1. distance1
2. distance2
3. distance3

But will not do so if the rank is static.

How can I make use of MongoDB's meta and sorting functionality to allow a dynamic ranking algorithm based on user input? Kind of like how Reddit uses upvotes to determine where a page ranks.

EDIT: holy shit fixed a dumb physics mistake

Comment: Are those different documents of a single collection? else each of the document is a collection themselves?

Comment: those (distance1,2,3) are documents in a collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient approach would be to update the `rank` field when you change the values in your application code (i.e. don't allow `time` and `velocity` to be set without also recalculating the `rank`). You can then add an appropriate index (or indexes) including the `rank` field to support your common queries (see [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) for some helpful background on creating indexes).

You could also compute `rank` dynamically via a query with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), but that would involve a very inefficient recalculation for all matching documents in the collection to determine result order.